# JqueryUI Dialogue box will not close upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have got to be missing something in plain sight.  The dialog will close with the close button in the top corner but  I have hidden that so that they have to answer the question. However, the dialog does not close upon click action on the buttons. I have looked at other posts on StackO but to no avail... What am i doing wrong here?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Age Disclaimer">Are you 21 years old?</div>

<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog ({ 
     autoOpen: true,
     width: 410
});

$("#dialog").dialog ({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
  buttons: {
     'Yes, I am 21 years old!': function() {
         $("#dialog").dialog('close');
     },
    'No, I am not 21 years old.': function() {
         $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can close the dialog by using `$("#dialog").dialog('close');`. Then it would be :

```
$("#dialog").dialog ({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
  buttons: {
     'Yes, I am 21 years old!': function() {
         $("#dialog").dialog('close');
     },
    'No, I am not 21 years old.': function() {
         $("#dialog").dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/n5v3ux64/

Comment: I have tried that you can see that on the 'Yes" button thats exactly what i did.  Oh and the 'dialogclose' was an expirement. I had it as just 'close' originally.  I'll edit that now.

Comment: @Edge as you can see in my jsfiddle, it works fine. So then, you need to provide more code / explain more of your problems

Comment: Yeah for sure I hear what your saying.  That's all the code that has to do with the dialogue so maybe some other code is interfering with it. Could it possibly be the preview function of Brackets I'm using?

Comment: That is the only issue I am having with the entire site as well so no other problems.

Comment: Ok so I ran the entire pages code in jsFiddle and it is having the same issue so you are correct. Some other part of my code is effecting it. Perhaps its the fact I ran the script in the html body instead of a separate .js file?

Comment: @Edge there has been a debate about puting js file inline with html or externally. but I would like to put it externally

Comment: Take a look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789679/existing-code-stops-newly-added-jqueryui-dialog-from-closing-upon-action-button